# Remap specific file/path in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

New to MVC routing, forgive the basic nature of the question.

Is it possible to configure the routing in ASP.Net MVC so that someone browsing to, say, http://www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml is redirected to a view that renders XML content?  I assume so but am not sure of a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a route before your default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Sitemap",
    "sitemap.xml",
    new { controller = "Sitemap", action = "Index" }
);
```

and then you could have a `SitemapController`:

```
public class SitemapController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = ...

        // Don't look for XmlResult, it's up to you to write it
        return new XmlResult(model);
    }
}
```

Now when you navigate to `/sitemap.xml`, the `Index` action of the `Sitemap` controller will get executed.

Comment: I think you should mention this new route should be above the default ones. because the order matters